# what version(s) of SQL Server work with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

What version(s) of SQL Server Express are compatible with Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition?  I have a machine with SQL Server Express 2008 R2 already installed - will VS2013 Professional work fine with that?

Comment: Yes, it will, go see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx

Comment: I think  SQL Server Express 2008 R2 works fine with vs 2013 any edition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQL Server is the tool to manage database,Visual Studio 2013 is the tool to write code .net,visual...,the code connect to database by connectionString, so I think The Visual Studio 2013 work find in any SQL Server version

Answer (score 0):

No!

If the version of SQL server is newer than the version of Visual Studio then you will get the message "This Version Not Supported" when you attempt to create a data connection

Comment: but his VS 2013 > the server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use newer version. But incase you already created a database in older version, you may need to migrate to new version.